# Error:...while parsing LambdaConverter.class Error:1 error; aborting Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Getting this build error in Android Studio. Did anybody face this kind of error? How to resolve this?

```
Error:PARSE ERROR:
Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:...while parsing com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/reflection/LambdaConverter.class
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: Could you please add more context to your question (Proguard, MultiDex...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing this from build.gradle the issue is resolved
`compile 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.9'`

Issue occurs when number of methods count exceeds a certain limit defined in Dalvic

Solving this problem with multiDexEnabled leads to more problems.
// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true

Cleaner way is to resolve the problem and not use multidex option.

For more options please refer to [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Comment: That is not what the error said. The error is because you have Java 8 compiled code and Android can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was using the .jar file for java 8(jdk 1.8). Removed it and included the .jar file for java 7 and it worked without errors.

Thanks to cricket_007